# Read mobile SMS through the site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mobile, mobile-website

Is it possible to read the SMS verification code that is sent to the mobile phone on the website and write the verification code automatically in the desired field so that the user does not need to fill in the field? Like verification codes in applications.
I use asp.net MVC

Answer (score 1):

No, a website cannot immediately read the SMS verification code that is given to a mobile phone.

The SMS verification code is often delivered to the user account's mobile phone number via a third-party SMS gateway provider.

The SMS verification code is read exclusively on the user's cell phone, and the code is not shared with the website or any other third-party service. This is done to preserve the user's privacy and to keep unauthorize people from accessing their account.

However, you may use other methods for two-factor authentication, such as sending the verification code to an email address or using a mobile app for authentication.

Comment: To register on the site, the steps are as follows:
1- The user enters his mobile number.
1- The SMS verification code will be sent to the mobile phone.
2- The user manually enters the code on the website.
In the second step, can it be done automatically only on mobile?